# How do I get the position on a virtual object (surface of a 3D-Model) at the point where i touched the object on screen

Tags: ios, swiftui, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

I am developing an interactive AR app in which you place a loaded 3D model on a qr code in the real world and then have the opportunity to "paint" on the surface of the model with your finger on the touchscreen.

the "painting" is already broken down by me to a placing of small spheres instead of using something like a linedrawer e.g.

There is something like a touchhandler and a function to place small red spheres an the taplocation in the scene.

i get my taplocation. then i try to fire a raycast into the scene. this should give me the position on the model. but when i try to place a sphere it appears in a slightly shifted position. additional it should only place spheres on the model, so the touch next to the model should lead to nothing.
it seems to me, that the raycast hits something else but not the shape of my model

i genereated a collisionshape created by RealityKit:

```
modelEntity.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
```

maybe you can help me get the right "pipeline" to solve the problem.